# Why is $\mathcal K=\{ v \in V: v \le \psi \}$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I ’m studying about obstacle problems at the moment and I came across with this statement:

> Let $V$ be a closed linear subset of $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$
>   is a bounded open connected subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\psi$ some
>   measurable function.Then the set $\mathcal K=\{ v \in V: v \le \psi
>  \}$  is **obviously** closed.

I ’m having a hard time understanding this "**obviously**" here. I have the following Theorem as a reference but I don’t see the connection:

THEOREM:Let $1\le p \le \infty$ and suppose that $\{u_n\}_n$ converges toward $u$ in $L^p(\Omega)$. Then there exists a subsequence $\{u_{nk}\}_k$ which converges to $u$ a.e in $\Omega$; moreover, there exists $u^{\ast} \in L^p(\Omega)$ such that $\vert u_{nk} (x) \vert \le u^{\ast}(x)$ for a.a $x\in \Omega$, any $k \in \mathbb N$

Should I consider $u^{\ast} \le \psi$? And what about $\nabla u_n$?

I would really appreciate if somebody could make this clear to me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about any derivatives at all. If $v_n \leq \psi$ and $v_n \to v$ in $W^{1,2}$ then  there is a subsequence $v_{n_k}$ converging almost everyehere to $v$. Just take limit in $v_{n_k} \leq \psi$ to get $v \leq \psi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply! But why such a subsequence  exist?

Comment: Convergence in any $L^{p}$ is enough to guarantee existence of such a subsequence. Look at the norm of $W^{1,2}$. Doesn't convergence in the norm of $W^{1,2}$ give you convergence in some $L^{p}$?.

Comment: yes....convergence for $u$ as well as $\nabla u$ in $L^2$. So I can just use the same Theorem for $w \equiv \nabla u$?

Comment: You are getting confused As I said you don't have to consider $\nabla u$ at all. Just use definition of  a closed set. If $u_n \to f$ in the norm of this space then $u_n \to u$ in $L^{2}$ norm so there is a subsequence as stated. The proof ends with that. Why consider any derivatives at all?

Comment: because $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1,2}$ means $u_n \to u$ and $\nabla u_n \to \nabla u$ in $L^2$...am I wrong? thank you very much for your time though

Comment: Yes, but for proving that the given set is closed the second fact is not needed. It is enough to use the fact that $u_n \to u$ in $L^{2}$ because this implies almost everywhere convergence of some subsequence.